# Create flat file that 'flattens' multiple rtansaction rows into one line in SQL*PLus

Tags: recursion, plsql, flat-file

As the title says, I need a method of flattening multiple rows into a one luine output per account. For example table looks like this:

Account     Transaction

12345678    ABC

12345678    DEF

12346578    GHI

67891011    ABC

67891011    JKL

I need the output to be:

12345678|ABC|DEF|GHI

67891011|ABC|JKL

The amount of transactions is unknown. For some accounts it could be 1 or 2, all the way up to 100's.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a customised version of  [Tom Kyte's STRAGG function](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402), like this:

```
select account||'|'||stragg(transaction)
from mytable
where ...
group by account;
```

The function as given uses commas to separate the values, but you can easily change it to use '|'.

An example using EMP (and with commas still):

```
SQL> select deptno || '|' || stragg(ename) names
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno;

NAMES
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10|CLARK,KING,FARMER,MILLER
20|JONES,FORD,SCOTT
30|ALLEN,TURNER,WARD,MARTIN,BLAKE
```

Comment: nice ! I had no clue something like this existed ! we had written a lot of code to achieve this !

Comment: Yes, it's a very handy function to have around.